# Value as column names in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
dat<-data.table(Y=as.factor(c("a","b","a")),"a"=c(1,2,3),"b"=c(3,2,1))
```

It looks like:

```
   Y a b
1: a 1 3
2: b 2 2
3: a 3 1
```

What I want is to subtract the value of the column indicated by the value of Y by 1. E.g. the Y value of the first row is "a", so the value of the column "a" in the first row should be reduced by one.
The result should be:

```
   Y a b
1: a 0 3
2: b 2 1
3: a 2 1
```

Is this possible? If yes, how? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using self-joins and `get`:

```
for (yval in dat[ , unique(Y)]){
  dat[yval, (yval) := get(yval) - 1L, on = "Y"]
}
dat[]
#    Y a b
# 1: a 0 3
# 2: b 2 1
# 3: a 2 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `melt/dcast` to do this.  `melt` the dataset after creating a row sequence ('N') to 'long' format, subtract 1 from the 'value' column where 'Y' and 'variable' elements are equal, assign (`:=` the output to 'value', then `dcast` the 'long' format to 'wide'.

```
dcast(melt(dat[, N := 1:.N], id.var = c("Y", "N"))[Y==variable, 
   value := value -1], N + Y ~variable, value.var = "value")[, N := NULL][]
#   Y a b
#1: a 0 3
#2: b 2 1
#3: a 2 1
```

Comment: note this will require a copy to save the object (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 0):

First an apply function to make the actual transformation.  We need to apply by row and then use the first element to name the second element to access and over write.  For some reason the values I was accessing in `a` and `b` were strings, so I used `as.numeric` to transform them to numbers.  I don't know if this is normal in `data.table`s or a result of using the apply statement on one since I don't use `data.table`s normally.

```
tformDat <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) {x[x[1]] <- as.numeric(x[x[1]]) - 1;x})
```

Then you need to reformat back to the original `data.table` format

```
data.table(t(tformDat))
```

The whole thing can be done in one line.

```
data.table(t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) {x[x[1]] <- as.numeric(x[x[1]]) - 1;x})))
```

Comment: This coerces all of the columns to `character`